# How to count distinct records

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could anybody please help me on SQL command?

I have a table (tbl_sActivity) that have below data:

> user_id | client_id | act_status |
>   1           |     7        |
>        cold     |
>   1           |     7        |
>      dealed   |
>   22         |     5        |
>        cold     |
>   1           |     6        |
>        cold     |
>   1           |     6        |
>       warm    |
>   1           |     6        |
>        hot       |
>   1           |     6        |
>      dealed   |
>   1           |     8        |
>       warm    |
>   1           |     8        |
>      dealed   |
>   21         |     4        |
>       warm    |
>   21         |     4        |
>      dealed   |

The out put should be

> user_id | Count_C_id |
>    1          |
>       3             |
>    21        |
>       1             |
>    22        |
>       1             |

I've searched from net and learnt that MS ACCESS cannot use COUNT(DISTINCT) function. So I'm stuck at this stage for days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this one. The "trick" is to have a subquery first to get all the distinct combinations of user and client IDs and then do the grouping per user:

```
SELECT
    user_id
  , COUNT(*) AS count_distinct_clients
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
          user_id, 
          client_id
      FROM tbl_sActivity
    ) AS tmp
GROUP BY
    user_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation is to make query without using sub-query.

Please find the below code which will be faster and accurate then subquery.

// Temp Table

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStudent(userId  int, c_id int , Name  varchar(MAX) )

SELECT max(userid) as UserId, count(c_id) as C_ID from #TempStudent 
GROUP BY userId
```