# Counting unique records by month

Tags: ms-access, unique, records

I'm a newbie to Access 2010.  I have a table:

```
ID  Mth OrderID Net Sales
1   1   3   36
2   1   2   12
3   1   2   20
4   2   1   10
```

I'd like to get a summary by `Mth` of the `OrderID` count, Quantity of those orders, and Net Sales of the those orders:

```
Mth Ordercount  Quantity    Net Sales
1   2   7   68
2   1   1   10
```

Is there a way to do this?

I'd also like to convert `Mth = 1` into `Month = Jan 2013` but have it list in date order, rather than alphabetically.

```
Mth
Jan 2013
Feb 2013
```

How do I do that?

So far, I've only been working with the design view and have not using an SQL code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a minute and learn how to format your questions (and hopefully answers, too) to make them easier to read. I’ve done that here, please check that I did not break anything. Also, tagging is meant to help others quickly find questions they can help with, which is why it’s a good idea to always include the programming language or tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done mostly in the design viewer of access although it would require creating more than one query and using those as a source instead of a table or you could write a sub select in sql code.

For your first question you will need to perform a distinct count on order id's based on month.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965336/sql-how-can-i-count-distinct-record-in-ms-access) question answers the same problem and will provide the output you need.

Once you have a query that provides the number of orders per month you can create a new query that joins the table and your query on month with `Net Sales` as a total field.  Where is quantity coming from in your source data?

To display the month number as month access has a [MonthName function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/monthname.php) you can use. You can add 2013 to this by adding `& " 2013"` to the end of the expression.

You can sort on month by adding your month field a second time for the sorting but uncheck show box.