# SQL counting certain columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have three columns:

**Course event**

Name, supervisor, place

```
AAAA     martha     3
BBBB     josh       2
AAAA     evelyn     1
AAAA     martha     4
AAAA     josh       5
```

**Course**

code, price

**Place**

id, name

I want to find courseevents that has been held at atleast 4 different places. Not including duplicates.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct place)` to count the # of unique places per event and only select those that have at least 4:

```
select name
from course_event ce
group by name
having count(distinct place) >= 4
```

Update:

```
select
    user_id
  , count(*) as count_distinct_places
from
    ( select distinct
          name, 
          place
      from course_events
    ) t
group by name
having count(*) >= 4
```

Comment: Hi this seems like a good solution, clean and easy to understand. I cannot get it to work with Access though, it gives me query error(missing operator) in query expression count(distinct place) >= 4

Comment: @Ilja ms-access does not support `count(distinct)`

Comment: well that sucks. Do you know any solution to this with ms-access SQL code?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965336/sql-how-can-i-count-distinct-record-in-ms-access